# AngularJS + Socket.IO + Authentication

Tags: angularjs, authentication, socket.io

I am curious how others are solving the following problem...

I have an angular application that requires user authentication. The user must log in to the system to make requests. The user must also be authorized to create a socket.io connection.

When the application first starts up I must determine if the user is already authorized. I was planning on looking in sessionStorage for a user object/token. Does that make sense? And if the user is not authorized, the application will make a request to get the current user. If/When that fails, a 401 error is returned and angular intercepts/prompts for a username/password.

Given that there are two different code paths for authentication (check sesssionStorage vs make a request and wait for the response) how do you trigger the requests for all the other information that is required for the application? Do you emit/listen to a LOGIN event that gets broadcast in both scenarios?

My plan was to wrap the socket.io connection attempt and the ".on(...)" calls inside of the LOGIN event, does that make sense?

And if you want to listen to socket.io events or grab information from the server in a controller that is loaded after the LOGIN event has fired, how do you trigger the data from being retrieved from the server?

Sorry for the long winded questions, but I've hit a road block and I'm wondering how others are managing all the authentication and different pieces of information that is required to get from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess let's go in order of question asked.

*Does it make sense to use sessionStorage to hold user auth info?*

Yes. You will need to decide between local/session Storage depending on how you want it to work. We decided we wanted the session to still be active for the time period that the backend recognizes, so even if the user closes the browser and reopens it, they will be logged in, and so we opted for localStorage instead of sessionStorage.

*How do you trigger the requests for all the other information that is required for the application? Do you emit/listen to a LOGIN event that gets broadcast in both scenarios?*

After login, we redirect the user to the "landing" page (route). All of our route/state changes wait on a resolve function which is doing the session auth. We only store the session id in localStorage. After the successful state change, the controllers that go with the newly loaded views start requesting data from our services. All of our controllers are designed to load data on init. So no, we do not use events. It feels like events should be used only as a last resort - and that is also the impression I get from core Angular devs since I get chastised for event usage in pull requests :)

*My plan was to wrap the socket.io connection attempt and the ".on(...)" calls inside of the LOGIN event, does that make sense?*

Maybe. I am not using socket.io outright, but instead have been experimenting with atmosphere (mainly because we had a java backend requirement). I do initiate the connection in the login success handler. But the general atmosphere event handling I have put into an application-level controller that is on <body>.

*And if you want to listen to socket.io events or grab information from the server in a controller that is loaded after the LOGIN event has fired, how do you trigger the data from being retrieved from the server?*

I could imagine (again using an app-level controller, or a service, or in my case, likely both) a function that returns the socket.io connection. A controller that has come into being could grab the socket.io stuff on init, and setup the listeners for the events that it is interested in.

My advice is to get all of your session and auth stuff worked out first, especially with regard to how you are going to do routing. Once all of it is working to your satisfaction, then add the socket.io stuff in. I realize that this might not be possible in all cases because perhaps you need something from the socket.io connection that is critical to your app even at an early stage.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly points me in the right direction. I was doing a fundamental thing wrong (e.g. not using resolve properties) so I think once I move my stuff in to the resolves, that should start to clean up the rest of my auth scheme.